# Solving shortest squared distance problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

The question is "The shortest squared distance, $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$, from the origin $(0, 0, 0)$ to a point $(x, y, z)$ on the plane $x + y + z = 1$ is"

I don't seem to understand where to start so an in-depth answer would be really helpful. Thank you.

(edit: The answer to this problem is 1/3)

Comment: This is a constrained optimization problem. One possibility would be to use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Can't you simply say the vector from the origin to $(x,y,z)$ is perpendicular to the plane, i.e., parallel to $(1,1,1)$, and find $(x,y,z)$ and hence $x^2+y^2+z^2$ from there?

Comment: @gangrene Could you elaborate further? I'm really confused with this problem.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Only the information above is given in the question. I'm not sure if what you said is allowed

Answer (score 1):

You know how the radius of a circle is perpendicular to the tangent?

Likewise,
the shortest segment from the origin to the plane $\color{blue}1x+\color{blue}1y+\color{blue}1z=1$

is perpendicular to the plane, i.e., in the direction $\color{blue}{(1,1,1)}$ , i.e., $(x,y,z)=(x,x,x)$.

If $x+x+x=1,$ then $x=\frac13,$ so $x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac13^2+\frac13^2+\frac13^2=\frac13.$

Comment: It would help if you could guide me further. It would help if you could show me how to solve this problem thoroughly. Thank you

Comment: @AmardasSingh There are infinitely many ways to define the distance between a point and a line or surface. One way is to use the *shortest* such distance when it exists. It's usually proved in elementary geometry that the distance between an outside point and a line is along the perpendicular from the point onto the line. The same is obviously true for a point and a plane.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Lagrange multiplier method the Lagrange function is $\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda) = f(x,y,z) - \lambda g(x,y,z)$. In you the specific case you minimize

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = x^2+y^2+z^2 - \lambda \cdot (1-x-y-z)$$

The partial derivatives are

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial x}=2x-\lambda=0 \Rightarrow 2x=\lambda \quad (1)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial y }=2y-\lambda=0 \Rightarrow 2y=\lambda \quad (2)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial z}=2z-\lambda=0 \Rightarrow 2z=\lambda\quad (3)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda }=1-x-y-z=0 \quad (4)$

Dividing $(1)$ by $(2)$ gives $\frac{x}y=1\Rightarrow x=y$, assuming $y,\lambda\neq 0$.

Dividing $(2)$ by $(3)$ results in  $\frac{y}z=1\Rightarrow y=z$, assuming $z,\lambda\neq 0$.

Plugging  $y$ for $x$ and $z$ into $(4)$: $1-y-y-y=0\Rightarrow 1=3y\Rightarrow y=\frac13$

Answer (score 1):

OK, then, here's another (geometric) way:

The shadow of any vector from the origin to a point in the plane on the vector $(1,1,1)$ has length $1/\sqrt 3,$ since for each such vector $\bf{v},$ we have that $|(1,1,1)| × |\bf{v}| \cos\phi=1,$ with $\phi$ being the angle between these vectors and the directing vector.

It follows that the smallest distance is the length of this shadow, and it's square is $1/3.$